# Pthreads and CudaMemcpyAsync

Tags: cuda, pthreads

I wrote a test program to test the following idea: (1) a cuda stream copies data to gpu. The copy is done in a pthread. (2) a second cuda stream reads and processes data. (3) One more data is copied by first stream only if the previous data is processed by the second stream.

However, it does not work: only copy first data and then waiting there.

```
#include "cuda.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

const int UNPROCESSED = 1;
const int PROCESSED = 2;
const int DONE = 3;
const int RUNNING= 0;
const int NUM_OF_DATA = 100;
const int NUM_OF_BLOCKS = 1;
const int THREADS_PER_BLOCK = 1;

//int data_states[NUM_OF_DATA];
cudaStream_t cuda_stream[2];
volatile int* process_state;
volatile int* d_process_state;
volatile int* d_copier_state;
int* d_data_state;
int* h_data_states;
cudaError_t cuda_status;

using namespace std;

void* copy_data(void* arg){
   int i=0;
   //cout << "in copy_data" << endl;
   while(i < NUM_OF_DATA){
      if (*process_state != UNPROCESSED){
         cout << "Now copy data " << i << " with state = " << h_data_states[i] <<  endl;
         *process_state = UNPROCESSED;
         cuda_status = cudaMemcpyAsync(d_data_state, &h_data_states[i], sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, cuda_stream[0]);
         if (cuda_status != cudaSuccess){
            cout << "Error when allocating pinned host memory (full_instance_states)" << endl;
         }
         i++;
      }
   }
   int copier_state = DONE;
   cudaMemcpyAsync((void*) d_copier_state, &copier_state, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, cuda_stream[0]);
}

__global__ void process_data(volatile int* data_state, volatile int* process_state, volatile int* copier_state){
   int i = 0;
   printf(" i = %d\n", i);
   while(*copier_state != DONE){
      printf(" i = %d, copier_state = %d, data_state = %d\n", i, *copier_state, *data_state);
      if(*data_state == UNPROCESSED){
        printf("now processing data %d\n", i);
        i++;
        // process data here, skipped
        *process_state = PROCESSED;
        *data_state = PROCESSED;
        //__threadfence_system();
      }
   }
   printf("process_data is done\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  int i;

  cudaSetDeviceFlags(cudaDeviceMapHost);

  cuda_status = cudaMallocHost((void**) &process_state, NUM_OF_BLOCKS*sizeof(int),  cudaHostAllocMapped);
  if (cuda_status != cudaSuccess){
      cout << "Error when allocating pinned host memory (full_instance_states)" << endl;
  }
  cudaHostGetDevicePointer((int**) &d_process_state, (int*) process_state, 0);

  cuda_status = cudaMalloc((void**) &d_copier_state, NUM_OF_BLOCKS*sizeof(int));
  if (cuda_status != cudaSuccess){
      cout << "Error when allocating pinned host memory (full_instance_states)" << endl;
  }
  cudaMemset((void*)d_copier_state, RUNNING, sizeof(int));

  cuda_status = cudaMallocHost((void**) &h_data_states, NUM_OF_DATA*sizeof(int), 0);
  if (cuda_status != cudaSuccess){
      cout << "Error when allocating pinned host memory (full_instance_states)" << endl;
  }
  for(i = 0; i < NUM_OF_DATA; i++){
     h_data_states[i] = UNPROCESSED;
  }

  cudaStreamCreate(&cuda_stream[0]);
  cudaStreamCreate(&cuda_stream[1]);
 pthread_t thread;
 int thread_state = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &copy_data, h_data_states);
  if(thread_state){
     cout << "Error: unable to create thread (produce_instances), "<< thread_state << endl;
     exit(-1);
  }


  //cout << "Starting kernel" << endl;
  process_data<<<NUM_OF_BLOCKS, THREADS_PER_BLOCK, 0, cuda_stream[1]>>>(d_data_state, d_process_state, d_copier_state);


  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  cudaFree(d_data_state);
  cudaFree((void*) d_copier_state);
  cudaFreeHost((void*) process_state);

  return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never allocate `d_data_state` in any way.  It is a NULL pointer throughout your program.

Therefore the usage here is invalid:

```
cuda_status = cudaMemcpyAsync(d_data_state, &h_data_states[i], sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, cuda_stream[0]);
```

And when I run your program, I get the error printout from the next line of code.

Since your kernel also uses `d_data_state` (which is an invalid pointer) I get various invalid global read errors if I run your code with `cuda-memcheck`.

Since you have not allocated anything for `d_data_state`, your code cannot possibly work.

You had several other issues in your code as well. As just one example:

```
int copier_state = DONE;
cudaMemcpyAsync((void*) d_copier_state, &copier_state, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, cuda_stream[0]);
```

In order for `cudaMemcpyAsync` to work as expected (i.e. be asynchronous, and overlap with other stream activity) the host memory must be a pinned memory area.  `int copier_state = DONE;` does not create a pinned allocation, so copying from that breaks the asynchronous overlap of the `cudaMemcpyAsync` operation.

Here is a version of your code that works correctly for me (now updated with some additional guards against race conditions):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)


const int UNPROCESSED = 1;
const int PROCESSED = 2;
const int DONE = 3;
const int RUNNING= 0;
const int NUM_OF_DATA = 100;
const int NUM_OF_BLOCKS = 1;
const int THREADS_PER_BLOCK = 1;

//int data_states[NUM_OF_DATA];
cudaStream_t cuda_stream[2];
volatile int* process_state;
volatile int* d_process_state;
volatile int* d_copier_state;
int* d_data_state;
int* h_data_states;
int* h_copier_state;
cudaError_t cuda_status;

using namespace std;

void* copy_data(void* arg){
   int i=0;
   cudaSetDevice(0);
   //cout << "in copy_data" << endl;
   while(i < NUM_OF_DATA){
      if (*process_state != UNPROCESSED){
//         cout << "Now copy data " << i << " with state = " << h_data_states[i] <<  endl;
         *process_state = UNPROCESSED;
         cudaMemcpyAsync(d_data_state, &(h_data_states[i]), sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, cuda_stream[0]);
         cudaStreamSynchronize(cuda_stream[0]);
         cudaCheckErrors("thread cudaMemcpyAsync fail");
         //*process_state = UNPROCESSED;
         i++;
         }
      }
   *h_copier_state = DONE;
   cudaMemcpyAsync((void *)d_copier_state, h_copier_state, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, cuda_stream[0]);
   cudaCheckErrors("thread cudaMemcpyAsync 2 fail");
//   cout << "Thread finished" << endl;
   return NULL;
}

__global__ void process_data(volatile int* data_state, volatile int* process_state, volatile int* copier_state){
   int i = 0;
   //printf(" i = %d\n", i);
   while(*copier_state != DONE){
      //printf(" i = %d, copier_state = %d, data_state = %d\n", i, *copier_state, *data_state);
      if(*data_state == UNPROCESSED){
        //printf("now processing data %d\n", i);
        i++;
        // process data here, skipped
        *data_state = PROCESSED;
        __threadfence_system();
        *process_state = PROCESSED;
        __threadfence_system();
      }
   }
  // printf("process_data is done\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  int i;
  cudaSetDevice(0);
  cudaSetDeviceFlags(cudaDeviceMapHost);
  cudaMallocHost((void**) &process_state, NUM_OF_BLOCKS*sizeof(int),  cudaHostAllocMapped);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMallocHost 1 fail");
  cudaHostGetDevicePointer((int**) &d_process_state, (int*) process_state, 0);
  cudaMalloc((void**) &d_copier_state, sizeof(int));
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMalloc 1 fail");
  cudaMemset((void*)d_copier_state, RUNNING, sizeof(int));
  cudaMallocHost((void**) &h_copier_state, sizeof(int), 0);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMallocHost 3 fail");
  *h_copier_state = RUNNING;
  cudaMallocHost((void**) &h_data_states, NUM_OF_DATA*sizeof(int), 0);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMallocHost 2 fail");
  for(i = 0; i < NUM_OF_DATA; i++){
     h_data_states[i] = UNPROCESSED;
  }
  cudaMalloc((void**) &d_data_state, sizeof(int));
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMalloc 2 fail");
  cudaMemcpy((void*)d_data_state, &(h_data_states[0]), sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  cudaStreamCreate(&cuda_stream[0]);
  cudaStreamCreate(&cuda_stream[1]);
  pthread_t thread;
  int thread_state = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &copy_data, NULL);
  if(thread_state){
     cout << "Error: unable to create thread (produce_instances), "<< thread_state << endl;
     exit(-1);
  }


  //cout << "Starting kernel" << endl;
  process_data<<<NUM_OF_BLOCKS, THREADS_PER_BLOCK, 0, cuda_stream[1]>>>(d_data_state, d_process_state, d_copier_state);


  cudaDeviceSynchronize();

  return 0;
}
```

As an aside, it's not necessary to have all the complexity of pthreads to run one extra thread.  After the cuda kernel launch, all of your pthread-code could have been inserted in the main host thread, and your program would still work correctly.  The host thread runs asynchronously to, and in parallel to, the device kernel, after a kernel launch.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I corrected it and now it works now. Thank you. The reason I needs a pthread for coping is that another thread will be needed to produce data for my real purpose. I will check volatile for array elements later.

Comment: I tried to run your program. But the program hang there after copy 19 data. If copier_state is copied from non-pinned memory (like in my program), the program finishes correctly. Any issue with my system or something else? I tried again later, it seems work correctly after the first time. Really weird.

Comment: when I copy from non-pinned memory, the program hangs.  I can't really explain the issues.  The code seems to work correctly for me, I am running on Linux with no display, cuda 6.5RC.

Comment: I used cuda/5.5.22. When I used cuda/6.5.11_rc, your program compilers, but had error when running it: Fatal error: cudaMallocHost 1 fail (CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version at robert.cu:82). Not sure it is our installation issue or not.

Comment: That error will occur with any CUDA program you run.  It indicates your setup has a mismatch between the installed CUDA version and driver version.  It has nothing to do with this issue.  I don't know how you installed CUDA 6.5RC, but apparently you didn't install the newer driver that should be used with it.

Comment: I come back to this problem again. I commented out the cout statements in copy_data and process_data, and then compile your program by "nvcc -arch=sm_20". If I ran the program multiple times, sometimes the program hanger there. Output of NVidia-smi shows that utility is 99%. Strace shows continuous looping of cclock_getTime and poll. Sometimes the program works normally after 100 runs. But sometimes the program after ten runs. What should I check for this issue?

Comment: There were race conditions between the updates of `process_state` and  `data_state`.  Both host and device are writing to both of these locations on each iteration, but only checking one of the 2 quantities before proceeding.  I have updated the code with a version that I think has these race conditions protected against.  I think your ping-pong strategy is overcomplicated and fragile.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works perfectly with 1000 runs. It seems that cudaStreamSynchronize is crucial. Why has the host cpu to wait until data is being copied to gpu? By the way, it seems fine without cudaSetDevice. When should cudaSetDevice be used. Last question, any better strategy to recommend for the synchronization between copy_data and process_data()?

Comment: 1. It seems you want me to unravel and parse out the race condition for you.  That's rather involved, and it sounds like you don't understand what a race condition is.  Start by reading up on race conditions, then carefully analyze and map out the host updates to `process_state` and `data_state` and the device updates, and see if you can spot anything that could be a problem. 2. `cudaSetDevice()` probably isn't necessary.  In a multithreaded app, it ensures that all threads are using the same context.  3. I would recommend reducing the sync arrangement to a single variable, not 3.

Comment: Is it possible that the order of cudaMemcpyAsync and "*process_state = UNROCESSED;" be switched by the compiler? This looks to be the only reason I can think of race condition. If their order is kept as in the program, initialized-->(copy_data)--> unprocessed-->(process_data) --> processed-->unprocessed should avoid race condition to update *process_state at the same time. The host only update *data_state at initialization. So no possible update by both gpu and cpu at the same time.

Comment: `cudaMemcpyAsync` is *asynchronous*.  There is no guarantee when it will happen, with respect to the host thread.  I would suggest learning more about CUDA before trying to construct a system like this.  To be clear, a multithreaded, multi-streamed, producer/consumer CUDA code is not a trivial app to construct.  If you have no experience with CUDA, it's not what I'd recommend to get started with and learn about. You should be fully familiar with the aspects of multi-streamed CUDA applications, overlap of copy and compute, async apis etc. SO comments are not the place to acquire this knowledge.

Comment: I think I figured out my problem (not the program posted here): when I copied something to gpu, the same address in cpu memory is used. So before updating the same cpu memory address and coping it to gpu, my program need cudaStreamSynchronnize to make suer the previous data content has been already copied to gpu. The program I posted here does not initialize process_state. Robert, thank you for your patience and discussions.